# Getting every possible permutation in a format python

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I'm trying to program a way to generate all possible combinations in this format:

```
01-01-01-A
```

Now I've already looked in the itertools.permutations and combinations libs and read examples of how they worked. Though my problem is different than the other questions I've read

the first range can go from 0-38 and the next 2 ranges can go from 0-9 and the letter can go from A-C. I'm currently stuck on how I can use itertools to generate all possible combinations using this format.

What I am currently thinking is having 1 list with 4 lists inside with each of those numbers:

```
first_value = []
second_value = []
third_value = []
fourth_value = ["A", "B", "C"]
final_value = []
for num in range(0, 39):
    first_value.append(num)
for num in range(0, 10):
    second_value.append(num)
    third_value.append(num)
final_value.append(first_value)
final_value.append(second_value)
final_value.append(third_value)
final_value.append(fourth_value)
for value in itertools.permutations(final_value):
    print(value)
```

I'm not really sure how I can program this.

Comment: You need to be precise about what you mean by "combination" and "permutation", they are not the same thing, and it's not obvious which one you want.

Comment: Try to use itertools.product

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry, I'm looking for permutation. I just noted that I looked into each one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
import itertools

map(lambda t: "-".join(t), 
    itertools.product(
        map(str, range(0,39)), 
        map(str, range(0,10)), 
        map(str, range(0,10)), 
        ['A', 'B', 'C'])
    )
```

Comment: Thanks so much. This is exactly what I needed! :)